# MS Surface drag & drop SurfaceListBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, pixelsense

Hey guys I'm working on the Microsoft Surface Table and I'm attempting to drag an item from 1 SurfaceListBox to another and recognize which SurfaceListBoxItem the other SurfaceListBoxItem was dropped on top of.  The SDK help as a great tutorial for dragging items from 1 SurfaceListBox to the next and just adding the content and removing it from the other.  If I set AllowDrop=True on the SurfaceListBoxItem the SurfaceListBox still captures the drop.  If I set it to false on the SurfaceListBox it doesn't recognize the drop at all.  Somehow I need to bury deeper on that drop or something.

Comment: Is there a question in this somewhere? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may take the coordinates and then do a hit test on the childs of the listbox. Never done this though.

Answer (score 0):

If the Background property of your drop target is null then the drop event will not occur. Check that your SurfaceListBoxItems have a valid background. (It can be Background=Transparent if you like).